# how to implement smallcaps in itextsharp

Tags: itext

[image]In one PDf i got small caps text the font size is 0.0. i have extracted font

```
using:------  

iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(curBaseline[Vector.I1], curBaseline[Vector.I2], topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]);
Single curFontSize = rect.Height;
```

int this code curfontsize i got 0.0. but i was able to extract font family.but not able to extract fontsize. so the text was not displaying.can anyone provide solution for this . Is there anyother method.?

thankyou

Comment: Please provide the PDF in question.

Comment: pdf link(PDB,MBA, deels SPD)  these are small caps text :https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88316921/Input%202.pdf

Comment: That PDF just uses a smaller font to render the small caps

Comment: can u please tell how to extract small caps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce your `rec.Height == 0.0` issue in

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(curBaseline[Vector.I1],
    curBaseline[Vector.I2], topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]);
Single curFontSize = rect.Height
```

Doing so I assumed you chose `curBaseline` to mean the start point of the base line and `topRight` to mean the end point of the ascent line. My result (outputting both width and height of that `Rectangle rect` and the text respectively for each `TextRenderInfo` object received by my `RenderListener`):

```
[140,29,   6,66] "nagement en beleid. Via omscholing ("
[ 11,87,   5,00] "PDB"
[  4,95,   6,66] ", "
[  9,36,   5,00] "MB"
[  4,37,   5,00] "A"
[ 26,76,   6,66] ", deels "
[ 11,28,   5,00] "SPD"
[  5,82,   6,66] ") "
[ 88,66,   6,66] "ben ik in het financiële v"
```

So I did **not** get a height of 0.0 but instead of 5.00 for "PDB", "MB", "A", and "SPD".

This result is produced using a fairly current iText version. Thus, you might want to update your library as a first measure. If that does not help, you may want to reveal your source code to review here.

**EDIT**

As discussed in the comments here I extended the test class to extract the actual font sizes (both the size of the **Tf** operand and the size after applying the current transformation and text matrices). The result:

```
[140,29,   6,66,   8,50] "nagement en beleid. Via omscholing (" ([, , , AAHACD+SlimbachStd-Book] at   1,00)
[ 11,87,   5,00,   6,38] "PDB" ([, , , AAGNLJ+SlimbachStd-Book-SC750] at   1,00)
[  4,95,   6,66,   8,50] ", " ([, , , AAGNLJ+SlimbachStd-Book-SC750] at   1,00)
[  9,36,   5,00,   6,38] "MB" ([, , , AAGNLJ+SlimbachStd-Book-SC750] at   1,00)
[  4,37,   5,00,   6,38] "A" ([, , , AAGNLJ+SlimbachStd-Book-SC750] at   1,00)
[ 26,76,   6,66,   8,50] ", deels " ([, , , AAHACD+SlimbachStd-Book] at   1,00)
[ 11,28,   5,00,   6,38] "SPD" ([, , , AAGNLJ+SlimbachStd-Book-SC750] at   1,00)
[  5,82,   6,66,   8,50] ") " ([, , , AAHACD+SlimbachStd-Book] at   1,00)
[ 88,66,   6,66,   8,50] "ben ik in het financiële v" ([, , , AAHACD+SlimbachStd-Book] at   1,00)
```

As you can see, the **Tf** font size is always 1.0 and the effective font size (after scaling) of your small caps is 6.38.

As I am mostly working with iText (not iTextSharp), I've done the necessary reflection and introspection stuff in Java, too. This is the code of the `RenderText` implementation I used:

```
public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    LineSegment curBaseline = renderInfo.getBaseline();
    LineSegment curAscentline = renderInfo.getAscentLine();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(curBaseline.getStartPoint().get(Vector.I1),
            curBaseline.getStartPoint().get(Vector.I2),
            curAscentline.getEndPoint().get(Vector.I1),
            curAscentline.getEndPoint().get(Vector.I2));

    try {
        System.out.printf("  [%6.2f, %6.2f, %6.2f] \"%s\" (%s at %6.2f)\n",
                rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight(),
                getEffectiveFontSize(renderInfo),
                renderInfo.getText(),
                Arrays.asList(renderInfo.getFont().getFullFontName()[0]),
                getFontSize(renderInfo));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

float getEffectiveFontSize(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,
            NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException
{
    Method convertHeight = TextRenderInfo.class.getDeclaredMethod("convertHeightFromTextSpaceToUserSpace", Float.TYPE);
    convertHeight.setAccessible(true);
    return (Float)convertHeight.invoke(renderInfo, getFontSize(renderInfo));
}

float getFontSize(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
        throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
{
    Field gsField = TextRenderInfo.class.getDeclaredField("gs");
    gsField.setAccessible(true);
    GraphicsState gs = (GraphicsState) gsField.get(renderInfo);
    return gs.getFontSize();
}
```

The analogous trick should be possible with .Net introspection and reflection mechanisms.

Comment: Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();Vector topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint(); 
   iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(curBaseline[Vector.I1], curBaseline[Vector.I2], topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]);
            Single curFontSize = rect.Height; this.lastBaseLine = curBaseline;
            this.lastFontSize = curFontSize; i used this.

Comment: thank u @mkl . can you please provide your code completely. i will check out with mine if anywhere i have missed out

Comment: Looks sensible. Which version are you using? I'll add my code add soon as I'm at my computer again (this comment is from my smart phone).

Comment: i updated dll now.i am using 5.4.0 but actual font sze is 6.38 i am getting 4.99. please have a look at snapshot above. thanku

Comment: No, the font size in the PDF is 5. If there was some caps/small caps font and those letters were lower case characters in that font, it's size might be those 6.38, but (in the PDF) those letters are uppercase characters in a 5 point font.

Comment: That been said, when I talked about **font sizes** here, I was using the definition from your code, i.e. the vertical distance between the ascent line and the base line. This is *not* the number usually referred to as **font size.**

Comment: can you please provide code of urs how to calculate fontsize?

Comment: To calculate the effective font size, you have to consider the font size given in the font selection operator, the current transformation matrix, and the text transformation matrix. Unfortunately these data are hidden in the text render info object. You can access then using reflection, though. Do you want am example for that?

Comment: @DashManipal I added an example using Java.