# Get fontsize from PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

While extracting text from PDF I need to extract font-size too. First I had extracted like this:

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
  curBaseline[Vector.I1],
  curBaseline[Vector.I2],
  topRight[Vector.I1],
  topRight[Vector.I2]);
```

In this I am not able to get exact font size. After that I tried using `renderinfo.gs.fontsize;`. In this `renderinfo.gs.fontsize` I will get a few text font size exact one but few I won't get exact font size. Where I will get font size has "1.0". Can anyone tell me the method I am using is correct. If NO is there any other method to extract font size using iTextSharp. I am using iTextSharp 5.4 version. Thank you in advance.

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections;
  // code java to C# conversion   
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        LineSegment curBaseline = renderInfo.Baseline;
        LineSegment curAscentline = renderInfo.AscentLine;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(curBaseline.StartPoint.get(ArrayList.I1), curBaseline.StartPoint.get(ArrayList.I2), curAscentline.EndPoint.get(ArrayList.I1), curAscentline.EndPoint.get(ArrayList.I2));

        try
        {
            Console.Write("  [{0,6:F2}, {1,6:F2}, {2,6:F2}] \"{3}\" ({4} at {5,6:F2})\n", rect.Width, rect.Height, getEffectiveFontSize(renderInfo), renderInfo.Text, renderInfo.Font.FullFontName[0], getFontSize(renderInfo));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    float getEffectiveFontSize(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) throws System.ArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException
    {
        Method convertHeight = typeof(TextRenderInfo).getDeclaredMethod("convertHeightFromTextSpaceToUserSpace", float.TYPE);
        convertHeight.Accessible = true;
        return (float?)convertHeight.invoke(renderInfo, getFontSize(renderInfo));
    }

    float getFontSize(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, System.ArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        Field gsField = typeof(TextRenderInfo).getDeclaredField("gs");
        gsField.Accessible = true;
        GraphicsState gs = (GraphicsState) gsField.get(renderInfo);
        return gs.FontSize;
    }
```

Comment: You also have to take the current transformation matrix into account, see the edit in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739221/how-to-implement-smallcaps-in-itextsharp/15752789#15752789).

Comment: @mkl it is in java if am not   wrong. and i tried converting code using java to c# software but it was not possible. Can anyone help using csharp please

Comment: If introspection and reflection in c# is too different from that in Java, simply copy the iTextSharp parser classes and make the required members and methods public.

Comment: @mkl ya i agree i used render.gs.Fontsize. where i made gs has public in textrenderinfo class of itextsharp parser  i used it but only few PDF font m able to extract.remaining PDF font-size it comes has 1.0 which is very small.

Comment: The method `ConvertHeightFromTextSpaceToUserSpace` with which you have to scale the graphics state's font size, is present in iTextSharp, too, and also is private. Make it public, too, and use it.

Answer (score -3):

Hope this would be useful

```
`
Font arial = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 28, Color.GRAY);
Font verdana = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 16, Font.BOLDITALIC, new Color(125, 88, 15));
Font palatino = FontFactory.GetFont("palatino linotype italique",BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
  10,
  Font.ITALIC,
  Color.GREEN
  );
Font smallfont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7);
Font x = FontFactory.GetFont("nina fett");
x.Size = 10;
x.SetStyle("Italic");
x.SetColor(100, 50, 200);`
```

can be used to set font size

Comment: if i am not wrong this can be used in creating pdf. i want in extracting text from PDF . i need to identify the font size which is there in PDF